# Fullcalendar. The event lasts for 2 days and is displayed in two cells of days. Angular

Tags: angular, calendar, fullcalendar

I have a problem with Fullcalendar. So that events do not stretch the calendar too much, and there was +3more. I added to the calendar options:

```
dayMaxEventRows: true,
views: {
  dayGridMonth: {
    dayMaxEventRows: 5,
  }
},
```

After that, the events that started yesterday and last until today are duplicated in both cells days. This is played if there is an Event Popover.

[image]

Yesterday's event, which lasts 2 days, is visible on the next day. How not to show the event on the next day?

[image]

I didn't find any relevant information that would help me

Comment: Can we have a [mre] of the issue please, including relevant event data (in JSON format). Also provide your fullCalendar version number. Thanks.